# Context is not updating text in React Native after state change

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a real doozy here and I can't wrap my head around it.

I have this component:

```js
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    if (myContext.value) {
      alert('true');
      //changes myContext.value to false
    } else {
      alert('false');
      //changes myContext.value to true
    }
  }}>
  <Text>{myContext.value ? 'working' : 'not working'}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

The weird thing that I don't understand is that the context IS changing the onPress function.  So if I click the button it will alert true at first and then false and back and forth as expected. What's not changing is the text that should be going between "working" and "not working".

This component is definitely within the scope of my Provider. I'm using `useContext` to get access to `myContext`.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2):

**The point to be noted here is that just changing `myContext.value = false or true` Will not trigger a re-render.**

I am not sure how are you handling the `value` change, But I've created a replica of what you want

Check out [this](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/context-api-usage) Snack to see the working example.

Create a Context as shown below

```js
import { createContext } from 'react';

const MyContext = createContext();

export default MyContext;
```

An example App.js component would look like

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import MyContext from './MyContext';

import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(true);

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ value, setValue }}>
      <MyComponent />
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

And your component where you want to perform this operation should look like this

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import MyContext from './MyContext';

export default function MyComponent() {
  const myContext = React.useContext(MyContext);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        if (myContext.value) {
          alert('true');
          myContext.setValue(false);
          //changes myContext.value to false
        } else {
          alert('false');
          myContext.setValue(true);
          //changes myContext.value to true
        }
      }}>
      <Text>{myContext.value ? 'working' : 'not working'}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm doing.  I know it's updating the value because when i click it the alert changes back and forth from true to false its just not updating the text  between "working" and "not working" you can see that in my text component.  Do you know of any reason why this might be happening?

Comment: Just look at the Snack that I provided in the answer. You'll see the text getting changed

Comment: Sure, I get that, but it's not changing in my project.  Do you know of anything that would cause this behavior.  It's a fairly large codebase

Comment: you use this `myContext.value = false` or this `myContext.setValue(false)`?